# What is a descriptor?

Tags: javascript

The method `Object.defineProperty` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)) accepts as third argument a "descriptor".

What is a descriptor?

Comment: It's right there under the "Description" header: "A property descriptor is...".

Comment: The link you provided seems to provide a pretty good definition under the part that says `A property descriptor is an object with the following fields:`

Comment: I vote up for this question and the accepted answer which is much easier to follow than the complicated explanation on MDN

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A *property descriptor* can be of two types: data descriptor, or accessor descriptor.

## Data descriptor

Mandatory properties:

- `value`

Optional properties:

- `configurable`
- `enumerable`
- `writable`

Sample:

```
{
    value: 5,
    writable: true
}
```

## Accessor descriptor

Mandatory properties:

- Either `get` or `set` or both

Optional properties:

- `configurable`
- `enumerable`

Sample:

```
{
    get: function () {
        return 5;
    },
    enumerable: true
}
```

Comment: It's not mandatory to define a `value` property for the _data descriptor_. If you don't set any value, it will be initialized to `undefined`. I also find this valuable to know that if you use `Object.defineProperty()` to create a descriptor, all undefined characteristics will default to `false` but if you use the literal way (dot/bracket notation or defining through the object literal) in both cases, other characteristics will be `true`.

Answer (score 5):

A descriptor is something that describes something. In this case it's just a plain object (`{...}`) with certain fields, that describes how the property should behave. Read further down the page to see what fields you can use.