# MDN JavaScript Inheritance Revisited - understanding the example

Tags: javascript

I was looking at the example on the MDN pages about [Inheritance Revisited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited) and thought it would be nice to have the `doSomething` methods actually *do* something. So I started out with the following code, based on the example:

```
function A(a) { this.varA = a };
A.prototype = { varA: null, doSomething: function() { console.log('do something with ' + this.varA) } };
function B(a, b) {
    A.call(this, a);
    this.varB = b;
};
B.prototype = Object.create(new A(), {
    varB: { value: null, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writeable: true },
    doSomething: { value: function() {
        A.prototype.doSomething.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log("do something with " + this.varB);
    }, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writeable: true}
});
var b = new B('a', 'b');
b.doSomething();
```

I copy and pasted the code into the Chrome console and expected to be seeing

```
do something with a
do something with b
```

but instead I got

```
do something with a
do something with null
```

What am I overlooking here? Shouldn't the call to "new B" result in the constructor which was defined above (function B(...)) being called? And if the constructor is called, shouldn't b.varB have a value? How do I need to change the example so the output is as expected?

Comment: Interesting... `this.varB = b;` does not *seem* to be executed. `b` does not have a property `varB`. It has something to do with the property definition. If you remove `varB: { value: null, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writeable: true }`, it works.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. @FelixKling could we assume the B's prototype overrides the instance's property value? I can't find a reasonable explanation to it.

Comment: @Fabrício: Yes it somehow seems to prevent assigning to it, although `writable` is set to `true` (if that even has an affect, properties are normally *always* assigned to object itself).

Comment: +1 Fascinating question. Interestingly, forgoing `Object.create` and just assigning `B.prototype.varB = null` directly (after calling `B.prototype = new A()`), seems to be fine.

Comment: The second parameter which OP is passing from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Syntax): "specify property descriptors to be added to the newly-created object, with the corresponding property names", I'm not familiar with term "descriptor" (was it introduced in ES5?) but one that is should be able to answer this question. There's also [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) which deals with descriptors.

Comment: OH! `writeable` is misspelled. It should be `writable`. `writable` defaults to `false`, so changing the value is not possible.

Comment: @FelixKling Nicely done, you've solved the mystery. `=]`

Comment: @FelixKling - Nice catch, but why would that mess with the direct assignment?

Comment: After reading this [descriptor question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9167181/1331430) (both answers) it made sense to me.

Comment: @Joseph: Yeah, it's strange, but I guess that's how these property descriptors work. Otherwise, whenever you inherit from an object (as here, creating a new instance), you could easily overwrite the non-writable properties, which seems to defeat the purpose of making them non-writable. And you don't want to have to make the property non-writable for each instance (which defeats the purpose of the prototype).

Comment: @FelixKling - How then can you set a property on the object without affecting the same-named property on the prototype?

Comment: @Joseph: You can't that's the point. It cannot be substituted with something else because it is protected.

Comment: @FelixKling - Then let me rephrase the question: Is there any way to protect a property on the prototype, while allowing individual objects to define their own property with a matching name?

Comment: @FelixKling Are you sure? http://jsfiddle.net/kcAZ2/2/ My guess is that said property gets automatically added to/inherited by each created instance and doesn't relate to the prototype one directly.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Seems you're right. `b.hasOwnProperty('varB')` is true: http://jsfiddle.net/kcAZ2/3/

Comment: That was a rapid wild guess, but I think it is stated in one of the linked MDN docs above somewhere as well.

Comment: @Joseph: Ah... well if the property is writable and you assign it directly to the instance, a new property is created on the instance, the one of the prototype is not affected. I think I misunderstood you first.

Comment: Changing `writable` to `false` doesn't add a property to the instance, very interesting.

Comment: @Fabrício: That's what I meant by my very first comment ;)

Comment: How properties are set seems to be specified here: http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.2, but it does not tell me much. I don't see how adding a new property to an object is prevented when  such a property is write-protected on the prototype. Something to investigate when I have more time ;)

Comment: @FelixKling You've found the typo which was causing the issue and also commented on the instance not having that property much ahead of us, IMO it is more than fitting for an answer.

Comment: @Fabrício: Well, although it started as an interesting question (and non-writable properties are interesting), since it was just a typo, I think it should be closed as too localized. I can still answer, but it should be closed either way.

Comment: Well yes, if you call it too localized I'll add my CV as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accidentally you specified `varB` as being **non-writable** and hence the assignment `this.varB = b` failed (or was ignored).

`writeable: true` should be spelled `writable: true` (without `e`). By default, properties defined using the a property descriptor are non-writable.

So the whole descriptor becomes:

```
varB: { value: null, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true }
```

Since you are assigning a value inside the constructor function anyway, you don't really have to use the descriptor though.

---

More information: [MDN - `Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: If the constructor's prototype has a non-writable property, you can't assign a property of the same name to the instance as to don't shadow the non-writable one "inherited" from the prototype. It is not very clear how/why but it makes some sense to me.

Comment: Exactly... I tried to follow it in the spec but either did not understand or was looking at the wrong part.

Comment: No problem, your answer is pretty complete and solves OP's issue nevertheless. Feel free to @ me someday if you make some sense out of the specs. `x]`

Comment: @Fabrício: I will :) Enjoy your day/evening/night!

Comment: @Joseph: You want to be notified too? Alright :D And have a good day/evening/night too! 't was fun :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its always fascinating that you can look over the same mistake a hundred times but a second pair of eyes will be able to point you right to it :-).