# Usage of defineProperties inside of a constructor function

Tags: javascript

I like to define properties by using the Object.defineProperties method. Moreover I like to have getter / setter.

I've figured out this example:

```
var Car = function(vendor, speed) {
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    vendor: {
      get: function() {
        return vendor;
      },
      set: function(newVendor) {
        vendor = newVendor;
      },
      enumerable: true
    },
    speed: {
      get: function() {
        return speed;
      },
      set: function(newSpeed) {
        speed = newSpeed;
      },
      enumerable: true
    }
  });  
}
```

What I don't understand is how to initialize the properties.

In my example: Would I have to write 'this.vendor = vendor' underneath the definitions?

Moreover: What's the purpose of the configurable-parameter?

The documentation says it specifies if or not a property descriptor can be changed.
What does that exact mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I don't understand is how to initialize the properties.
>   In my example: Would I have to write 'this.vendor = vendor' underneath the definitions?

that is correct to initialize properties you would do `this.vendor = 'vendorValue';`
 (treat them like simple property)

> Moreover: What's the purpose of the configurable-parameter?

`configurable` if set to true allows to redefine property descriptor with `Object.defineProperty` or `Object.defineProperties` by default it is false and error is thrown if you are redefining property with `Object.defineProperty` or `Object.defineProperties` again.

*descriptor* is description of property that you are passing to `Object.defineProperty` (or `Object.defineProperties`)

```
{
 get: function() {
    return vendor;
  },
  set: function(newVendor) {
    vendor = newVendor;
  },
  enumerable: true
},
```

Answer (score 0):

### Initial Value

> In my example: Would I have to write 'this.vendor = vendor' underneath the definitions?

You could. But you can also use the *value* descriptor like so...

```
vendor: {
    set: function (newVendor) { ... },
    enumerable: true,
    value: 5 // here is the initial value
}
```

### Configuable

> What's the purpose of the configurable-parameter? The documentation says it specifies if or not a property descriptor can be changed. What does that exactly mean?

To specify if the property may be deleted or it's *descriptors* changed. This means, if set to false you cannot, once defined, change the getter, setter, enumerable, writable, etc, descriptors using `Object.defineProperties`.

Say you have some object `var hat = {}`. We create a property on that object `hat.style = "fancy"`. This property is configurable by default. However when using `Object.defineProperties` it is `false` by default.

So say we change `writable` (a property descriptor) to be `false`. Now `hat.style = "wacky"` does not work, the value of `hat.style` remains `"fancy"`. However, lets change the `style` property to non-configurable by setting `configurable` as `false`. Now we cannot set the `writable` descriptor back to `true`, we cannot even set `configurable` as `true` again.

### Resources and further reading:

- [MDN | defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)
- [What is a descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167181/what-is-a-descriptor)
- http://arqex.com/967/javascript-properties-enumerable-writable-configurable

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish I could rate your answer up. But I haven't earned enough credit until now ...