# Using ES decorators on class get and set methods

Tags: javascript, decorator, ecmascript-next

is it ok according to the decorator [proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/) to have a decorator on a class getter or setter? Or are they only allowed on normal methods? e.g.

```
class Foo extends Bar {

  @override
  get someProp() {
    super.someProp + 2;
  }
}
```

some libraries / frameworks provide such decorators. But for example the babel parser babylon marks that as an error!

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have a decorator on any property definition in the class body. The decorator of course needs to be able to deal with the kind of descriptor.

Comment: is there anything unclear about my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's perfectly fine from the perspective of the decorator to be applied to a setter/getter field, basically any field. Since "normal" property and setter/getter property differ in the type of property descriptor - [data descriptor vs accessor descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167181/what-is-a-descriptor) and the decorator is applied to a property descriptor it can be applied to any property, including "setter/getter" and "method" properties.

For example, you can change the setter to "normal" property inside the decorator:

```
function removesetter(klass, prop, descriptor) {
    return {
        value: 5,
        writable: true
    }
}

class Foo {
    @removesetter
    get someProp() {
        return 3;
    }
}

const f = new Foo();
console.log(f.someProp); // 5
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Would be there any issue if there are both the setter and getter with a decorator in the class? or it is enough if the get or set property of the descriptor is only updated in each decoration?

Comment: and is it possible in the decorator function to determine if the method called upon is a setter or getter?

Comment: @user2520818, the decorator is called with the descriptor. it specifies both getter and setter. I don't think it's possible to determine the method it's called upon. Both getter/setter are essentially just one property with a special accessor descriptor and hence you can't apply the same decorator to both setter/getter since it doesn't make sense