# How does angular method decorator work?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-decorator

In this [Angular decorator tutorial](https://netbasal.com/inspiration-for-custom-decorators-in-angular-95aeb87f072c), the tutorial explains that a [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle) decorator (lodash [throttle](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/6cb3460fcefe66cb96e55b82c6febd2153c992cc/throttle.js) function) can be made this way:

```
import t from 'lodash.throttle';

export function throttle( milliseconds : number = 500 ) : MethodDecorator {
   return function ( target : any, propertyKey : string, descriptor : PropertyDescriptor ) {
   const original = descriptor.value;
   descriptor.value = t(original, milliseconds);
   return descriptor;
  };
}
```

And use in the following class

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts-page',
  template: `
     <posts [posts]="posts$ | async"></posts>
  `
})
export class PostsPageComponent {
  constructor( private store : Store<any> ) {
    this.posts$ = store.select('posts');
  }

  @HostListener('document:scroll')
  @throttle()
  scroll() {
    console.log('scroll');
  }
}
```

I wonder how throttle works to change scroll function. Could anyone explain or let me know how I can see the compiled code? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`throttle` is a property decorator and it means that it's job is usually to modify the class (object) [property descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167181/what-is-a-descriptor). The descriptor before the modification has the `value` pointing to `scroll` function:

```
{
  value: scroll() { console.log('scroll'); },
  ...
}
```

The decorator accepts this descriptor and replaces the original `value` with the new decorated function returned by the call to `t`:

```
function ( target : any, propertyKey : string, descriptor : PropertyDescriptor ) {
   // save original value 'scroll'
   const original = descriptor.value;
   // overwrite original value with the decorated function returned by `t`
   descriptor.value = t(original, milliseconds);
   return descriptor;
};
```

If the decorator returns the descriptor it's then used to define the property instead of the original descriptor.

You can read more about decorators in the article:

- [Implementing custom component decorator in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d)

Comment: all methods have descriptors since a method is a property pointing to a function